# Struts 2 action method and struts.convention.result.path not working

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, action, actionresult

I have problem with Struts2 action method and `struts.convention.result.path`
Here is my `struts.xml`

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="" />
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/.*\.(html|jsp),/static/.*"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <package name="user" namespace="/user" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="loginAction" method="login">
            <result name="success">login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
<struts>
```

When I run url `"localhost:8080/venus/user/login"`. It display error `"HTTP Status 404 - /venus/user/login.jsp"`

If I change `login()` method to `execute()` method, it works.
Or if I change to `<result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp</result>`, it works.

Can anyone explain and teach me how use action method with result path config in xml?
Thank you very much!

Comment: When using Convention plugin, xml configuration isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the absolute path name.

```
<result name="success">/login.jsp</result>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Convention plugin, xml configuration isn't needed:

- com.mycompany.actions.user -> namespaces "user"
- LoginAction -> login.action
- LoginAction#execute -> success -> user/login.jsp
- LoginAction#login -> success -> user/login(-login|-success).jsp